# Because natural weapons are light, could I "dual wield" a tail and claws in dnd 5e with a Path of the Beast barbarian?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

I couldn't find this in any official material but when I looked it up it said that natural weapons are light, meaning that hypothetically I'd be able to use claws and a tail simultaneously. Tasha's Cauldron of Everything says that you can "manifest *a* natural weapon". This implies you can't use two, right?

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157645/do-natural-weapons-count-for-two-weapon-fighting addresses whether natural weapons are light - they are not.

Comment: I'm really unsure about whether this actually *is* a duplicate, but I would like to know *where* you looked up and found natural weapons to be light. It may well be something there which is worth addressing.

Comment: I'd like to add, having it as a duplicate is not a bad thing in and of itself, it still can help people find the detailed, existing answer. If you are happy with the other answer, great. If you feel that it should not be a dupicate, you can update with clarificaton, and ask to reopen it.